# Can anyone tell me why this object in illustrator is changing over other colors depending on PDF output?

Tags: print-design, layers, transparency

This illustrator object is in CMYK, in a CMYK document, at a Normal / 100% transparency setting. When the file is exported in High Quality Print it displays correctly on screen, but prints similarly to the way the x1a PDF shows digitally.

Here is the file! https://send.firefox.com/download/6e9ca3b08f/#RQgQP12g5V9kj02k9GvpNA

x1a PDF (Top) vs High Quality Print PDF (Bottom):

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/tlgVI]

Comment: Just to cover my bases: This illustrator object is in CMYK, in a CMYK document, at a Normal / 100% transparency setting. When the file is exported in High Quality Print it displays correctly on screen, but prints similarly to the way the x1a PDF shows digitally.

Comment: Err  the images are side by side.

Comment: @user118761 can we get the actual file instead of an imgur post?

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit to the imgur link. Now it should be showing correctly above.

Comment: I don't mind uploading the file ... but I am new on here. What's the best way to do this? :)

Comment: @user118761 Well there's any number of services out. Use anything safe like google drive but you can try the one made by the firefox team it's pretty safe and fast https://send.firefox.com/

Comment: Thank you! See file here: https://send.firefox.com/download/6e9ca3b08f/#RQgQP12g5V9kj02k9GvpNA

Comment: Thank you Ovaryraptor for editing my post ... I just signed up today to ask this question. :P

Comment: I'm confused... are you actually printing something or are you merely having differences with the **digital** files as you preview them? Acrobat job options for PDFx1 and "high quality print" **are** different and will handle some objects differently. I'm unclear which "version" you see as the "correct" version. In all probability PDFX1a is honoring (or dishonoring) overprints.

Comment: This "object" is in a file that needs to go to print for an ad, where the object is actually a corporate logo (I just changed the logo in the example above for privacy). Normally when I send ads to print, the output I select is "High Quality Print". With this file however, the object (logo) appears fine digitally -but when I print it, the object looks transparent (like in the x1a file as shown above, even though I'm not selecting x1a as the output). I've tried replacing the object, punching it out to create a new object, and changing the object's color ... but nothing seems to work.

Comment: So then I would assume the "object" has overprints turned on for either fills or strokes. I'm afraid this may not be solvable without direct examination of the file. -- before you say it's there... ---> *"This link has expired or never existed in the first place!"*

Comment: Scott, thank you! Somehow Overprint was checked on ... I didn't even know this was a thing? I never learned about it in college. Maybe I was sick that day. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your first "PDFx" Image would indicate the appearance of **Overprints**.

Your second "High Quality File" image would indicate *no* overprints.

The difference could be anything from the object itself being set to overprint in the application (Illustrator), to a setting for the Job Options when you create the PDF, to even merely the preference in Acrobat/Reader to display overprints.

Chances are if you track down *where* the overprints are being introduced, you will probably track down the display difference.